# Get all id values from checked checkbox in table

Tags: javascript, checkbox, html-table

```
<table id="tab" border='1' style='width:100%'>
        <tr ><td>'hi'</td><td><input type='checkbox' id='1'/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>'hi'</td><td><input type='checkbox' id='2' /></td></tr>
        <tr ><td>'hi'</td><td><input type='checkbox'id='3' /></td></tr>
        <tr ><td>'hi'</td><td><input type='checkbox'id='4' /></td></tr>
</table>
```

this is example code, i need to return list of if that are checked, so if i check all of them i get
lit[1,2,3,4]
if i select only fist 2
list[1,2] and so on.
Please help me!

Comment: Post your attempt(s)

Comment: Do not use ordinals to represent ids. Add a prefix, or just use a class.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
var list=[]
$("#tab :checked").each(function(i,e){
  list.push($(this).attr("id"))
})
```

Comment: Answers without `jquery` or framework tag should be answered in vanilla JS

Comment: @Adam Thanks for learning.
Anyway I will leave it so that it might be useful for something

Answer (score 0):

Find all the checkbox elements and filter those which are checked.

```js
const checkedCheckboxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'))
  .filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked)
console.log(checkedCheckboxes)
```

```html
<table id="tab" border='1' style='width:100%'>
  <tr>
    <td>'hi'</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='1' /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>'hi'</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='2' /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>'hi'</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='3' /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>'hi'</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='4' /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be assigning a value to each checkbox instead. Please do not use the ID attribute to store data.

When you are ready to grab the IDs, reference the value of the field.

```js
document.querySelector('.btn-disp').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const ids = [...document.getElementById('tab')
    .querySelectorAll('td input[type="checkbox"]:checked')]
      .map(cb => cb.value); 
      
  console.log(`Selected IDs: ${ids.join(', ')}`);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 0.75em;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

table, td {
  border: thin solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 2em !important;
}
```

```html
<table id="tab">
  <tr>
    <td>Item #1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item #2</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="2" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item #3</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="3" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item #4</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="4" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<button class="btn-disp">Display Selected IDs</button>
```